# Redirect to a page in ended function

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I have a javascript code that play a video after another video previously load in the video src. What i want is when the second video ended automatically redirect me to other page, here is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">


var videoplayer = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
var video = $('video')[0];




  videoplayer.addEventListener('click',function(){
  videoplayer.play();
},false); 

  videoplayer.addEventListener('ended',function(){
  var nextVideo = "C:/Users/Video Turismo/Desktop/Spots y videos/Vidios/Lamb.mp4";
  videoplayer.src = nextVideo;
  videoplayer.pause();
  $('video').unbind('ended');
  window.location("www.google.com");
 
},false); 



 


</script>
```

```html
  <video width="100%" height="50%"  controls  id="videoplayer" >
        <source src="C:/Users/Video Turismo/Desktop/Spots y videos/Vidios/NEGAS.mp4">
      </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ask if the video.src is not already the nextVideo and then change location or whatever. This way you know the second video ended.

```js
var videoplayer = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
var video = $('video')[0];

videoplayer.addEventListener('click', function(){
  videoplayer.play();
},false); 

videoplayer.addEventListener('ended', function(){
  var nextVideo = "C:/Users/Video Turismo/Desktop/Spots y videos/Vidios/Lamb.mp4";
  if (videoplayer.src == nextVideo) {
    window.location("www.google.com");
  }
  videoplayer.src = nextVideo;
  videoplayer.pause();
}, false);
```

```html
  <video width="100%" height="50%"  controls  id="videoplayer" >
        <source src="C:/Users/Video Turismo/Desktop/Spots y videos/Vidios/NEGAS.mp4">
      </video>
```